# AngularJS project ng command not recognized but npm run ng works

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm

Important point: this is Angular**JS** project.
I cannot install @angular/cli.
I have installed node v8.11.3 (with NPM v6.7.0).
Then installed AnguarJS

npm install angular@1.7.2

At this point, I cannot run

```
 ng serve
```

Error: 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

However, I can run:

```
npm run ng serve
```

And everything runs as it should.
I can't find where ng is in order to put it in my path, yet npm seems to have no trouble finding it.

Any suggestions?  NOTE: I am not allowed to move to Angular 2+.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried installing angular/cli globally?

Comment: Yes, .... but no luck.

Comment: I am finding this CLI that was being added  does not support the version the project was originally written for.  When I changed to the latest CLI (and took steps to perform the audits), the project runs correctly.
My apologies.

Comment: Are you running it in Windows or Ubuntu ?@yogi bear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finding this CLI that was being added does not support the version the project was originally written for. When I changed to the latest CLI (and took steps to perform the audits), the project runs correctly. My apologies.